# Will killing Python made problems for Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, python

If I kill Python on my server, will it made problems for Apache?

Comment: What do you mean by kill?  Does your server have any webapps using python?

Comment: i disabled python form some reasions. no, there are no web apps that uses python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python and Apache aren't related, unless your app is making use of Python. When you say killing, I assume you mean deleting. While deleting won't have any direct effect to Apache, most Linux distributions make heavy use of Python to support the operating system directly. So deleting it may have many undesired effects.